# pyodbc - write a new column of data to existing table in ms access

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I have a ms access db I've connected to with (ignore the `...` in the drive name, it's working):

```
driver = 'DRIVER={...'
con = pyodbc.connect(driver)
cursor = con.cursor()
```

I have a pandas dataframe which is exactly the same as a table in the db except there's an additional column. Basically I pulled the table with pyodbc, merged it with external excel data to add this additional column, and now want to push the data back to the ms access table with the new column. The pandas df containing the new information is `merged_df['Item']`

Trying things like below does not work, I've had a variety of errors.

```
cursor.execute("insert into ToolingData(Item) values (?)", merged_df['Item'])
con.commit()
```

How can I push the new column to the original table? Can I just write over the entire table instead? Would that be easier? Since `merged_df` is literally the same thing with the addition of one new column.

Answer (score 1):

If the target MS Access table does not already contain a field to house the data held within the additional column, you'll first need to execute an `alter table` statement to add the new field.

For example, the following will add a 255-character text field called `item` to the table `ToolingData`:

```sql
alter table ToolingData add column item text(255)
```

Comment: You were correct that the column did not exist in my table. You're bit of code worked perfectly and I confirmed it did add an empty column to the `ToolingData` table. My last line of `cursor.execute("insert into ToolingData(Item) values (?)", merged_df['Item'])` still will not execute though, it throws an error `Error: ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid SQL data type  (67) (SQLBindParameter)')`. Do you know what could be causing this? And yes, I changed the new column name to `Item`

Comment: Does your table already contain data? Does `merged_df` contain more than one record?

Comment: Yes the original table does contain data. The table `ToolingData` in ms access has 8420 rows and 25 columns, the `merged_df` has the same 8420 rows but with 26 columns, the additional one being what I merged from the excel file

Comment: OK, in that case an `insert into` statement may not be appropriate, since this will append **new** records to the table, rather than updating the `item` field value for the **existing** records. Furthermore `insert into <table> values <values>` will only permit you to append a single record at a time. Instead, if the table is to contain all data held by `merged_df`, it may be easier to clear the table data and repopulate it with the data from `merged_df`, otherwise you'll need to use an `update` query, identifying each record to be updated using the data held by `merged_df`. I hope this helps!

Comment: @55thSwiss - If you're looking for a way to easily replace the existing table with your DataFrame you may want to check out the [SQLAlchemy dialect for Access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/).